# are nonatomic and atomic thread unsafe in objective c?

Tags: thread-safety, atomic, nonatomic

I read that nonatomic and atomic both are thread unsafe. but nonatomic is faster because it allows faster access means asynchronously and atomic is slower it allows slower access synchronously.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by _thread unsafe_. Atomics do give you certain guarantees, in particular they prevent interleaved partial writes, which will yield garbage values on concurrent non-atomic writes.

Comment: @ComicSansMS,thread safe means if thread A executing no other thread can execute at this time until it completes.                                  With "atomic", the synthesized setter/getter methods will ensure that a whole value is always returned from the getter or set by the setter, regardless of setter activity on any other thread. So if thread A is in the middle of the getter while thread B calls the setter, an actual viable value will be returned to the caller in A. then how it would be thread safe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `atomic` property in Objective C guarantees that you will never see partial writes.

That is, if two threads concurrently write values A and B to the same variable X, then a concurrent read on that same variable will either yield the initial value of X, or A or B. With `nonatomic` that guarantee is no longer given. You may get *any* value, including values that you never explicitly wrote to that variable.

The reason for this is that with `nonatomic`, the reading thread may read the variable while another thread is in the middle of writing it. So part of what you read comes from the old value while another part comes from the new value.

The comment about them both being thread-unsafe refers to the fact that no additional guarantees are given beyond that. [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) give the following example here:

> Consider an `XYZPerson` object in which both a person’s first and last
>   names are changed using atomic accessors from one thread. If another
>   thread accesses both names at the same time, the atomic getter methods
>   will return complete strings (without crashing), but there’s no
>   guarantee that those values will be the right names relative to each
>   other. If the first name is accessed before the change, but the last
>   name is accessed after the change, you’ll end up with an inconsistent,
>   mismatched pair of names.

A purist might argue that this definition of thread-safety is overly strict. Technically speaking, `atomic` already takes care of data races and ordering, which is all you need from a language designer's point of view.

From an application-logic point of view on the other hand the aforementioned *first-name-last-name* example clearly constitutes a bug. Additional synchronization is required to get rid of the undesired behavior. In this application-specific view the class `XYZPerson` is not thread-safe. But here we are talking about a different level of thread-safety than the one that the language designer has.

Comment: Thanks for clarification for atomic and nonatomic, It means nonatomic is more reliable to use like such scenarios (ex: XYZPerson ) . but can you specify what could be scenarios for atomic where we should declare property with atomic access?

Comment: @Nitesh I never said that nonatomic was more reliable. In fact, with nonactomic, the results in the XYZPerson example could be disastrous, leading to data corruption and/or crashes. The point was that atomicity is [not the only means](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html) to synchronize multi-threaded code. The go-to example for using atomics are lock-free data structures, which can be useful in performance-critical code with a very high degree of concurrency.